# C++20 concept which requires the existence of an exact function signature

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following example for the calculation of the absolute difference between two values.

```
template<class T>
auto abs_diff(const T _a, const T _b) {
    return (_a > _b) ? (_a - _b) : (_b - _a);
}
```

For some build-in types `std::abs` provides superior performance, so if `std::abs(T x)` exists I want to use it (let's assume we are not interested in the different under-/overflow behavior in case of integers). To this end I tried to add the following constrained template function

```
template<class T> requires requires (T x) { std::abs(x); }
auto abs_diff(const T _a, const T _b) {
    return std::abs(_a - _b);
}
```

Now all types for which `std::abs` exists will use this specialized version. However also all types which are **implicitly convertible** to such a type will use it, which is undesirable. So my question is: is there a way to require the existence of a function with exact signature in a concept (i.e. the existence of `std::abs(T x)` and not only the fact that `std::abs(x)` compiles).

**Note:** The above example is mostly for illustration and could, at least for my application, be fixed by constraining the return type using `requires (T x) { { std::abs(x) } -> std::same_as<T>; }`. However I am interested in a general solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: "... which is undesirable." Why is it undesirable? Is there something in particular you're trying to avoid?

Comment: How do you define "exact signature" here? Should the existance of a function template, from which the correct function can be instantiated, also satisfy the concept?

Comment: @Barry In this particular case, I have a Fixed point class which is implicitly convertible to `double`. So while taking the absolute difference between two such Fixedpoint numbers is possible in exact arithmetic, using the above function would yield an unnecessarily inexact result as double. However there are also other scenarios apart from the `abs_diff` example where I would like to prevent implicit casts.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Interesting point, haven't thought about it before, but I think that, yes it should.

Comment: @Haatschii: But what if the user passes a `short`? There is no explicit `std::abs` for that. And what about other built-in types that aren't given overloads and yet rely on non-user-defined conversions to make `std::abs` work

Comment: @NicolBolas In the way I formulated the question, it should use the unconstrained template in that case. If you want to use `std::abs` also for `short`, `char` and their unsigned counterparts, you could change the constraint to `requires (T x) { std::abs(x-x); }`, which is what the function actually requires. As the difference of two `short`s yields an `int`, it would do what you want (well, currently it does anyway as implicit cast are allowed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can test instead if the overloaded function address expression `&std::abs` can convert to a pointer to function with the desired signature. Or we could, except that C++20 doesn't allow forming pointers to most standard library functions.

Leaving this original answer here for information. It would be a valid pattern for an overloaded function name which is not in the standard library. And it often works anyway, but we shouldn't count on that to continue with newer library versions.

```
#include <cmath>

template<class T>
auto abs_diff(const T _a, const T _b) {
    return (_a > _b) ? (_a - _b) : (_b - _a);
}

template<class T> requires requires (T (*fp)(T)) { fp = &std::abs; }
auto abs_diff(const T _a, const T _b) {
    return std::abs(_a - _b);
}
```

See a [test on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/r8z65n).

When this technique is used on a name that includes matching function templates, the constraint can also be satisfied if no non-template function is an exact match, but one most-specialized function template can deduce its arguments so that the type of a specialization is exactly `T(T)`.

(There is a `std::abs` function template declared in `<complex>`, but it can never exactly match type `T(T)`.)

Comment: Actually `std::abs` can include a function template, from `<complex>`. I'll update things later.

Comment: Looks great, thank you! For `std::complex` the constrained template is not considered, however this is correct because in that case the return type of `std::abs` is not the same as the argument type and the signature does not match.

Comment: Are the `std::abs` overloads defined as [addressable](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/library#namespace.std-6)? That's a very good solution in general, but standard library functions would put a massive caveat to this.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Interesting, I hadn't seen that new requirement. I just knew [the rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/member.functions#2) from C++17 and earlier, saying only that non-virtual member functions in the standard library do not necessarily have the exact signatures described in the Standard (implying, I think, all other functions and function templates were "addressable").

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica So in that case, would you agree the question is somewhat ill-posed, because it's not actually clear what "if `std::abs(T x)` exists" means?

Comment: @aschepler - Yeah, I concur. And upon further reflection, there's another fly in the ointment. C++20 allows certain standard library functions to be implements as functors (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/namespace.std#footnote-173). That's another caveat. I think the conclusion is that one simply better not try this with standard library functions.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica , @aschepler Well, that's really unfortunate if using this for standard library functions is ill-formed. Pondering about it some more I came up with a solution which works via a proxy class and the fact that at most one implicit user-defined conversion is performed, see https://godbolt.org/z/7bMx41. Note, the result is different from the above solution, as it still allows standard conversion sequence, e.g. using `short` will call the specialized function (which is fine for my applications). What do you think?

Comment: @Haatschii - Neat. Only thing I'd change is to make the helper deal in `T&`. That way you aren't implicitly requiring the type to be copy-able. How about posting it as an additional answer, for posterity?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Good point, will definitely change the argument to `const T&`. Posted it as an additional answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a result of the discussion of @aschepler's answer I came up with the following solution which should also work for standard library functions, as `std::abs` is one:

```
template<class T>
struct BlockImplicitConversion {
    BlockImplicitConversion(const T& _arg);
    operator T();
};

template<class T>
auto abs_diff(const T _a, const T _b) {
    return (_a > _b) ? (_a - _b) : (_b - _a);
}

template<class T> requires requires (T x) { std::abs(BlockImplicitConversion(x)); }
auto abs_diff(const T _a, const T _b) {
    return std::abs(_a - _b);
}
```

The rational is, that at most one implicit user-defined conversion is performed. Therefore the use of the proxy class `BlockImplicitConversion` prevents further implicit casts. At the same time standard conversion sequences are still allowed, e.g. for `short` the specialized template is called and a cast to int is performed.

[Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/MsqvcE)

Comment: No loss to me if you'd like to move the checkmark to your own answer, since my answer has an important flaw.